# Первичный ключ БД id or string

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, relation, foreign-key

Допустим есть `User`, у которого бывают 2-3 статуса `"pending"`, `"active"`, `"blocked"`.

Для сохранения целостности есть таблица `statuses :id, :name`

Ну и 2 варианта этот статус выставить.

1)
Мне кажется, что лучше сделать первичным ключом `name`, отказавшись от `id` навесить внешний ключ на это поле.

Тогда можно делать `User.set_status("active")`

2) Коллеги говорят, что это неправильный подход. Надо чтобы обязательно был `id`. Это позволит быстрее производить поиск, про какие-то древовидные индексы говорят.

Однако, в процессе разработки установка статуса усложняется.

```
status_id = find_status_by_name("active")

User.set_status(status_id)
```

Подскажите плиз, чем 1-й вариант, так существенно хуже второго?

Своим нубским взглядом, вижу только минусы второго варианта и плюсы первого.

Comment: А как быть с тем что на PK накладывается ограничение уникальности?) Читайте основы...

Comment: *Для сохранения целостности есть таблица statuses :id, :name* Непонятно, как именно Вы её используете. И в какой форме хранится соотв. атрибут в основной таблице User. Из текста вопроса (если там ВСЁ верно) следует, что в основной таблице хранится именно текст статуса, а не его идентификатор в справочной таблице. PS. Думаю, ради целостности и кошерности Вам стОит почитать справку про ENUM...

Comment: Вариант 3, и быстро и просто: `CREATE TYPE user_status AS ENUM ('pending', 'active', 'blocked');`

Comment: @NickProskuryakov так никто не предлагает сделать какое-то поле не уникальным, если что) А без утверждения уникальности поля name - бд не позволит сделать это поле внешним ключом. С основами то все в норме)

Comment: @Akina да так и предлагается использовать. вместо status_id = find_status_by_name("active") и
User.set_status(status_id) делать просто User.set_status("active"). А на уровне бд связь, которая проверяет что такой статус действительно есть. В общем, вышли из положения, в другом комменте ответил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

int легковеснее строки => из этого вытекают следующие достоинства:

1. Индекс будет занимать меньший размер
2. Таблицы, которые будут ссылаться на таблицу со статусами будут
       меньше весить.
3. Быстрый поиск. Для того, что бы СУБД сравнить на равенство строку
       выполняется посимвольное сравнение, чего нету в числах.

Comment: Ну, в целом, в итоге к тому и пришли. На текстовую строку мне внешний ключ навесить запретили, зато разрешили навесить на числовую. Сделали статусы id, code:integer,name:string и внешний ключ навесили на код. В итоге просто делаю User.set_status(2). И разработка удобнее, и недостатков никто придумать не смог. Всем спасибо.